# SVG <text> element bounding box changes on transform

Tags: javascript, html, svg

As I understand it, `getBBox()` is supposed to ignore the transformations applied to the element it's measuring.

eg: if I have: `<g transform="scale(0.5, 0.5)"><rect width="100" height="100" /></g>`, calling getBBox on `<g>` will always return `width: 100, height: 100`, no matter what the `scale()` args are. However, this does NOT appear to be the case when using a `<text>` element instead of `<rect>`. The size of `<text>` reported by `getBBox()` changes as the transformation changes.

Full example:

```js
const gNode = document.querySelector("g");

const dimensionsBB = () => {
  console.log(gNode.getBBox());
}

// trigger every time a change in size is detected
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(dimensionsBB);

resizeObserver.observe(gNode);

// update transformation every second
setInterval(() => {
  gNode.setAttribute("transform", `scale(${Math.random()}, ${Math.random()})`);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <text>Text goes here</text>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

In this example, the resizeObserver is triggered each time the scale changes, and the dimensions reported by getBBox() are different each time (with slight variations).

Why? And is there a way to always get a consistent result?

Comment: Because the font and kerning etc change to try to keep the text as legible  as possible. Why is it a problem?

Comment: Because another transformation is triggered each time the text size changes (in this case, squishing the text so that it fits within a certain area) -- except changing the transformation changes the text bounding box, which changes the transformation etc etc etc.

Comment: turn off the reize observer when you transform and then turn it on again afterwards.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank You!

One note to future readers: calling unobserve(element) and then observe(element) will cause the callback to be called immediately, so you should ignore the callback the first time it is called after observe(element) is called